# How to convert JSONObject to java object

Tags: java, json, object, pojo

I have an `Event` class which uses the builder pattern to set fields and finally adds fields to a `JSON` object.

```
public class Event{

  private EventProcessor eventProcessor = new EventProcessor();
  private String userName;
  private String userID;

  public Event setUserName(String userName){
     this.userName = userName;
     return this;
  }
  public Event setUserID(String userID){
     this.userID = userID;
     return this;
}

  public void toJson(){
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

   if(null != userName)
   json.put("userName", userName);
   if(null != userID)
   json.put("userID", userID);

  // need help to convert json to "event"
   eventProcessor.addToQueue(event);
  }
 }
```

The EventProcessor class

```
  public class EventProcessor{

   static{
  EventQueue eventQueue = new EventQueue<Event>();
 }

  public void addToQueue(Event event){

    eventQueue.add(event);
   }

 }
```

I used to pass `json` into `eventProcessor.addToQueue()` method and set `eventQueue = new EventQueue<JSONObejct>()` and `public void addToQueue(JSONObject event)`. This works for me. But now I need to just pass a POJO to the `addToQueue(Event event)` method. How can I change the code and convert the `json` result to `event` object and pass it as a parameter to the `addToQueue(Event event)` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i convert JSON to JAVA object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127231/how-can-i-convert-json-to-java-object)

Answer (score 5):

1. You can use Gson to convert JSONObject to java POJO:

   ```
   Event event = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Event.class);
   ```
2. You can use Jackson to do the same:

   ```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Event event = objectMapper.readValue(json.toString(), Event.class);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is a `Builder Pattern` yet, my question is why are you parsing the object into a JSON and back to the object again? 
Cannot you just past the object itself to the method? Like `addToQueue(this);` ?